# active directory show locked users which are not expired

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Is there a way to show the locked users, not disabled (if the password has typed wrong 3 time), which are are not expired (account not expired) either with AD query or a powershell script.
I searched on the net but couldn't find a solution.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Please, first search the internet for it. There are literaly thousands of scripts or one liner out there doing what your'e asking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work if your looking for locked out accounts which are not yet expired or without an expiration date set:

```
Search-ADAccount -LockedOut | where { $_.AccountExpirationDate -gt (Get-Date) -or $_.AccountExpirationDate -eq $null }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way. You could import `ActiveDirectory` module and use `Search-ADAccount` cmdlet.

```
Search-ADAccount -LockedOut -UsersOnly | Where-Object { $_.PasswordExpired -eq $false }
```